# Add column in pandas vectorized

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, tf-idf

i have a Term-Frequency matrix saved as a pandas dataframe.

```
     1000  Merkwürdig  Mindestens  Error  ...  Periode  bildet  30  Button
0       0           0           0      0  ...        0       0   0       0
1       0           1           0      2  ...        0       0   0       0
2       0           0           0      0  ...        0       0   0       0
3       0           0           0      0  ...        0       0   0       0
4       0           0           1      0  ...        0       0   1       0
..    ...         ...         ...    ...  ...      ...     ...  ..     ...
121     0           0           0      0  ...        0       0   0       1
122     0           0           0      0  ...        0       0   0       0
123     0           0           0      0  ...        0       0   0       0
124     0           0           0      0  ...        0       0   0       0
```

For each row i want to count the word occurence, add a column called 'count' at the end, and save the wordcount for each row.

```
     1000  Merkwürdig  Mindestens  Error  ...  Periode  bildet  30  Button    count
0       0           0           0      0  ...        0       0   0       0        0
1       0           1           0      2  ...        0       0   0       0        3
2       0           0           0      0  ...        0       0   0       0        0
```

Iterating over each row and column is probably not the best soution, so could this be vectorized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`.sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html?highlight=sum#pandas.DataFrame.sum) method

```
df['count'] = df.sum(axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Pandas has a sum function which will do what you need [`pd.sum()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html). You will need to set the axis=1 to tell it to sum across rows instead of columns. See below:

```
df['count'] = df.sum(axis=1)
```